# IIS 8.0 ignores the fixed Regular Time Interval for recycle

Tags: iis

I have deployed a web service with a very long fixed time interval(432000 mins) set up for worker process recycling. However, the Worker process keeps recycling every 2000 mins(not fixed every time), and I was getting logs saying "recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit". I was wondering if there is something else trigger the recycling? or is there any time limitation actually ignore my setting for the recycling? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have disable the worker process idle timeout by set the idle timeout to 0

Comment: Web services aren't designed for what you are trying to do, surely a windows service would be less effort to achieve the same? Set it up so that your web service communicates with it and you won't have to worry about timeouts!

Comment: I am fine with the recycling with some fix time interval for some long period. not some unpredictable minutes. I am just curious if the IIS does not support for a long time interval with fixed value, why it allow you to set the number at first place?

Comment: Hi Firing, Thanks for your reply, I do have a windows service running to keep my web service stay awake every 30 mins to avoid it is killed by idle time out. But the recycle still happens.